# Removing the item with onClick and eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the JS code, there is a part which prints some number of items, and next to each item there is an icon for removing the item next to it:

```
 <img src="images/remove.png"  class="remove" onClick="remove_item(${index})">
```

So, when the user clicked a bin the item next to it will be removed by the function below. The point is that items are need to be stored in an array called `list`. So item will be removed from `list`. The function `render` is for printing the items again.

```
function remove_item(index) {
  list.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
  render(list);
```

The code which is up is working perfectly. However the issue is that the task is needed to be done by using eventListener. For that `img` part is edited like below.

```
<img src="images/remove.png"  class="remove" data-index="${index}">
```

And the part which will remove the item from `list` is like below.

```
let remove = document.querySelectorAll(".remove"); 
Array.from(remove).forEach((el) => {
el.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    let index = el.getAttribute('data-index');
    list.splice(index, 1);
    render(list);
    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
})});
```

The problem is that, code is working only when page is refreshed before each click to any icon. So after clicking the icon, I have to refresh and then click again for removing some other item. How I can fix that?

Comment: You're removing eventListeners when `render(list)`. You actually need to remove the list item, not redraw the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-render the list the elements are all replaced, which strips the event handlers. You should probably just remove the actual element:

```
el.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    let index = el.getAttribute('data-index');
    list.splice(index, 1);
    el.remove();
    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
})});
```

Either that or run the code again after render which attaches the event handlers. Whatever makes the most sense with how you're rendering.

Comment: After you remove the element from the list, the list indexes no longer correspond to `data-index`.